# theoritical density distribution plot in r

Tags: r, graph, plot, ggplot2

I have data like the following:

```
type1 <- c(rep(1,49), rep(2, 30), rep(3, 20), rep(4,1))
type2 <- c(rep(1,10), rep(2, 20), rep(3, 40), rep(4,20), rep(5,10))
type3 <- c(rep(5,49), rep(4, 30), rep(3, 20), rep(2,1))

dat2 <- data.frame(dens = c(type1, type2, type3), lines = rep(c("a", "b", "c"), 
each = 100))
```

Here is histogram:

```
require(ggplot2) 
ggplot(dat2, aes(x = dens, fill = lines)) + geom_bar(position="dodge")+ theme_bw()
```

[image]

The density plot do not work exactly as this is discretely measured:

```
ggplot(dat2, aes(x = dens, fill = lines)) + geom_density(alpha = 0.5)
```

Beside I want to produce a smooth theortical distribution. I tried beta distributions like the following, I am not sure how can I get best fit to my data as above (dat2).

```
dat3 <- data.frame(dens = c(rbeta(4000000, 1, 3, ncp = 0),
 rbeta(4000000, 2, 2, ncp = 0), rbeta(4000000, 3, 1, ncp = 0))
                   , lines = rep(c("a", "b", "c"), each = 4000000))
#Plot.
ggplot(dat3, aes(x = dens, fill = lines)) + geom_density(alpha = 0.5) + theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: So you now a beta density and an empiric discrete density that have been plotted. What are you asking for? It looks like you have success.

Comment: @Dwin I plotted the above curve as guess, how do I know parameters of beta distribution that fits to my emperical data (dat2) ?

Comment: You may need to be looking for the various functions with names like `fitdistr`. Try `MASS::fitdistr` and `fitdistrplus::fitdist`.

Comment: There could, of course, be problems with such methods since fitting a beta distribution to discrete data will necessarily involve ignoring the structural ties in the data. It appears that the original data is multinomial in character and that the "best fit" is simply the observed distribution which is what your first plot shows. You may want to explain in more detail what the goals really are. This seems more a problem with your statistical education and posting on CrossValidated might be more appropriate.